# Python error loading flask: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

I'm really new to Python and I'm trying to do a tutorial on using flask. When I run the below code:

`from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)`

`@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"`

I get the following error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/PycharmProjects/flask/test_webapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask`

This doesn't make any sense to me as when I run:

`python -m pip list`

Flask 1.1.1 is on the list.

I am using Python version 3.7.4.

I realise this questions has been asked before but after carefully reading through I can't find the correct answer. I realise this is quite basic but any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Environment? Virtual environment, Anaconda or plain python or?

Comment: I'm using Pycharm

Comment: with or without anaconda?

Comment: Are you using any virtualenv?

Comment: I downloaded pycharm as part of the anaconda, and no I'm not using virtualenv. Apologies if I'm not giving the correct info for you to help. I've been using Python for about a week so it's all very new!

Comment: np, ok so you have anaconda, which is a virtualenv itself too. Did you started Pycharm from Anaconda Navigator? Where did you check `python -m pip list`?

Comment: No I have Pycharm as a separate application. So when I'm working on the project I load my script via this separate pycharm app.  To check the list I ran the above code in the terminal by selecting the folder where the pycharm project is, right clicking and opening the terminal from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203423/discussion-between-geeocode-and-mrmoleje).

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip list` answers in terms of Python 2.x

If you're using Python 3.x, you need to do `pip3 install flask`

Answer (score 0):

Module Flask is installed for Python 2 (Python), but not for Python 3 (Python3) that you are using.

So, install it as `pip3 install Flask`